# Erro ao Compilar Projeto Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Acabei de criar um projeto em Xamarin, não adicionei nada no projeto mas, quando vou tentar compilar retorna o erro:

> Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Se colocasse o código da Activity seria mais fácil descobrir, mas bem provavelmente você está herdando sua(s) Activity(s) da classe `AppCompatActivity`, assim o tema daquela(s) Activity(s) precisa ser do AppCompat, para resolver é só ir em values e depois em `styles.xml` (caso não tenha, vá direto no `AndroidManifest.xml`) e mudar o `android:theme=""` para "`Theme.AppCompat`" ou para algum compatível (Isso vai mudar o tema de todo o projeto, se quiser mudar de apenas uma Activity pode declará-la no `AndroidManifest.xml` e setar o tema apenas dela, mas isso é desnecessário se quiser apenas resolver esse erro)